# Need to send message to other users, not the sender, over websocket

Tags: c#, websocket, publish-subscribe

I'm building a publish/subscribe mechanism over websockets. I have the websocket working, but how do I send the message from userA to userB, userC, and userD (these are other users that are subscribed to the pub/sub).

I'm using websocketsharp and I have the list of sessions that are open, so I was trying to use SendTo, but I can't get it working.

I just need a point in the right direction.

By the way, I can easily send from userA to server, from server back to userA, but I can't figure out how to forward to userB, userC, userD who are also subscribed.

Here's a small code snippet of what I'm attempting to do:

```
   class DDPServer : WebSocketBehavior, IClientSession
    {
        private SessionInfo sessionInfo;
        public static WebSocketSessionManager sessionQueue { get; set; } 
        // more stuff here
    }
```

sessionQueue is assigned all the sessions.

So, now I have all the sessions. The request is received by the socket server, passes through the pub/sub mechanism (which provides a list of the subscribed users), and now I attempt to send the data back out using something like:

```
DDPServer.sessionQueue.SendTo("test", "3d0f491cfb654dd4839337608b19f849");
```

where 3d0f491cfb654dd4839337608b19f849 is the session id.

Comment: send it to the server and the server resends it to the client.

Comment: I can send it to the server just fine, I can send it back to the sending client just fine, but how do I forward it to the other subscribed clients?

Comment: Could you show some code for clarification? Not sure I'm understanding what your issue is if you can send/receive from server.

Comment: I just want to forward to the other clients. There's a SendTo method in WebSocketSessionManager, but I can't get this to work. It takes in (byte data, string id), what's the id in this case??? The session id, user id???

Comment: The server has to know what other clients are subscribed, the server uses that knowledge to forward the messages. The client should not know what other clients are subscribed.

Comment: Yep, got that, the clients have no idea who else is subscribed. I'm just trying to send from userA to server, server does its thing, server sends to subscribed userB. That's it. I just need to know the method for doing that. I think I figured it out. SendTo("some text", sessionId).

Answer (score 0):

WebSocketSessionManager maintains the open connections, so using that with .SendTo("string data here", "string session id here") I was able to send to any other client.

So, I will subscribe users, store the channel with the list of subscribed users in the database, pull those users out, look for the sessions associated with those users (if there are any), then run a for loop to SendTo each session.